# Change Number of fields based on selection in first field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to change number of fields based on selection in the first field.

I want the second field to be a selection or text input based on the selection in the first field.

I am getting one more field based on selection but how to get multiple fields?

My HTML code:

```
<form method="post" action="" >
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Search By </label>
        <select class="form-control margin-bottom-20"  name="search1" id="search1">
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option value="name">Name</option>
          <option value="mobile">Mobile</option>
          <option value="program_name">Program</option>
          <option value="program_schedule">Program & Schedule</option>
          <option value="program_schedule_shift">Program, Schedule & Shift</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Detail </label>
        <select class="form-control margin-bottom-20"  name="date" id="date">
        <?php include 'get_sch.php'; ?>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group"> 
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" id="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

My jQuery code is:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#submit").click(function() {
          var search1 = $('#search1').val();
          var detail = $('#detail').val();
          var dataString = 'search1=' + search1 + '&detail=' + detail;

          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "get_enquiry_details.php",
              data: dataString,
              cache: false,
              success: function(result) {
                  $("#date").html(result);
              }

          });
      });
  });
```

PHP Code:

```
$group = $_POST['search1'];
$gender = $_POST['detail'];

$selectquery = "SELECT * FROM `enquiry` WHERE `$group` = '$gender'" ;

$group_result = mysql_query($selectquery, $conn);

while ($container_id_record = mysql_fetch_assoc($group_result)) {
    $i++;
    echo "<tr class='gradeA odd' role='row'><td class='sorting_1'>" .
         $container_id_record['enquiry_date'] . "</td><td>" .
         $container_id_record['name'] . "</td><td>" .
         $container_id_record['mobile'] . "</td><td>" .
         $container_id_record['program_name'] . "</td><td>" .
         $container_id_record['schedule'] . "</td><td>" .
         $container_id_record['shift'] . "</td><td>" .
         $container_id_record['remark'] . "</td>";
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking..

Comment: Where is your $("#date") in HTML code?

Comment: Show your php code too.

Comment: You appear to have two questions (possibly it is hard to tell if there is any actual question in your posting). If you have two questions then choose one and ask it here clearly enough that people can understand it and offer you answers. Once that question is resolved ask your other question in a new question.